# How to derive the orthogonal projection form $\mathbf P_H=\mathbf H (\mathbf H^H \mathbf H)^{-1}\mathbf H^H$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection

I saw the formula below in this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.331.6329&rep=rep1&type=pdf

It said 
Assume that

$\mathbf H$ is a complex matrix of size $n \times m $,having full column rank

$\mathbf S$ is a complex matrix of size $n \times t$,having full column rank

the well-known formula to build an orthogonal projection whose range is $<\mathbf H>$ is

$\mathbf P_H=\mathbf H (\mathbf H^H \mathbf H)^{-1}\mathbf H^H-----(a)$

Now if we examine the matrix $(\mathbf H \mathbf S)$,the orthogonal projection onto the linear subspace $<\mathbf H \mathbf S>$ is

$$
  \mathbf P_{HS}=(\mathbf H \mathbf S)\begin{pmatrix}
    \mathbf H^H \mathbf H & \mathbf H^H \mathbf S\\
    \mathbf S^H \mathbf H & \mathbf S^H \mathbf S\\
  \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf H^H \\ \mathbf S^H\end{pmatrix} -------(b)
$$

I want to ask is that how does the (a) come?because in my thinking,the orthogonal projection is like

$proj_\mathbf u(\mathbf v)=\frac{<\mathbf v, \mathbf u,>}{<\mathbf u, \mathbf u,>}\mathbf u$

Second,$\mathbf H$ become $\mathbf H \mathbf S$,so $H^H$ become\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf H^H \\ \mathbf S^H\end{pmatrix},i can also understand.However,why will the $(\mathbf H^H \mathbf H)^{-1}$ become 
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \mathbf H^H \mathbf H & \mathbf H^H \mathbf S\\
    \mathbf S^H \mathbf H & \mathbf S^H \mathbf S\\
  \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$

Comment: Are you aware of the [least squares formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Matrix/vector_formulation) of $\mathbf H x = y$, 
$$
\mathbf H^H \mathbf H \hat x = \mathbf H^H y?
$$

Comment: If you would like a reference (other than the linked wiki page), Gilbert Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra covers this. In this context, we can simply replace any transposes with Hermitian-transposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for $proj_u$ is correct when you project along the line defined by $u$.
Here we are projecting in a subspace spanned by the column of $H$.
You start from the property that $v - proj_{H}(v)$ is orthogonal to any vector spanned by the columns of $H$:
$$
H^T \left( v - proj_{H}(v) \right) = 0
$$
or
$$
H^T v = H^T proj_{H}(v)
$$
But $proj_{H}(v) = H x$ as it is spanned by the columns of $H$
$$
H^T H x = H^T v
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
x = (H^T H)^{-1} H^T v
$$
And you get
$$
proj_{H}(v) = H x = H (H^T H)^{-1} H^T v
$$

Based on your dimensions, $\mathbf{HS}$ denotes $\left[ \mathbf{H}, \; \mathbf{S} \right]$ the matrix of dimension $n \times (m + t)$. The rest of the derivation is correct assuming that $\left[ \mathbf{H}, \; \mathbf{S} \right]$ remains full rank.

Comment: Why does $(H^TH)^{-1}$ become $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \mathbf H^H \mathbf H & \mathbf H^H \mathbf S\\
    \mathbf S^H \mathbf H & \mathbf S^H \mathbf S\\
  \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$,not $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \mathbf S^H \mathbf H & \mathbf S^H \mathbf S\\
    \mathbf H^H \mathbf S & \mathbf H^H \mathbf H\\
  \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$

Comment: $(H^T H)^{-1}$ should be replaced with $([H, S]^T [H, S])^{-1}$. The matrix $[H, S]^T$ is $(m+t) \times n$:
$\begin{pmatrix} H^T\\ S^T\\ \end{pmatrix}$.
So the product is
$$\begin{pmatrix} H^T\\ S^T\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} H & S\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} H^T H& H^T S\\ S^TH & S^T S\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\ \mathbf{z}\ $ is any $\ n\times 1\ $ column vector, then $\ \mathbf{z}_P=\mathbf{P}_H \mathbf{z}\ $ is in the column space of $\ \mathbf{H}\ $, and

$$ \left\langle \mathbf{z}_P,\,\mathbf{z}- \mathbf{z}_P\right\rangle=\left\langle \mathbf{P}_H \mathbf{z},\,\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{P}_H \mathbf{z}\right\rangle = \left\langle \mathbf{z},\, \mathbf{P}_H\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{P}_H ^{\,2}\mathbf{z}\right\rangle = 0\ ,
$$
because $\ \mathbf{P}_H\ $ is hermitian, and $\ \mathbf{P}_H ^{\,2}=\mathbf{P}_H\ $.  So $\ \mathbf{z}_P\ $ is the orthogonal projection of the vector $\ \ \mathbf{z}\ $ onto the column space of $\ \mathbf{H}\ $.

Your example of $\ proj_{\mathbf{u}}\left(\mathbf{v}\right)\ $ is just the special case of when $\ m=1\ $, and the column space of $\ \mathbf{H}\ $ is one-dimensional—spanned by $\ \mathbf{u}\ $.